# Does the logic that proves the halting problem unsolvable also apply to series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic

Would it be possible to apply the proof that the halting problem is unsolvable to a proof that a function $$Q(i)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(i)$$ where $$P(i)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
n,\quad when \quad i \quad converges\\ 
1/(n^2),\quad when \quad i \quad diverges
\end{array}
\right. $$ where $i$ is a representation of the series.

It seems that $Q(<Q>)$ would fall under the same contradiction that the halting problem does. Is this correct, or does the same proof not apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is under the assumption that your diagonalising series $Q$ has the following definition:

> $Q = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n)$ where $$P(n)= \begin{cases}
> n, &\text{if the }n\text{th series converges} \\ 
> n^{-2}, &\text{if the }n\text{th series diverges}
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $\langle S_n \rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ is some enumeration of series.

There are at least two problems with this:

1. Even restricting to series whose $n$th term is either $n$ or $n^{-2}$, there are $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$ such series, and so the "diagonalising" series $Q$ may very well not be among the series in the initial (necessarily partial) enumeration.
2. Even if you could arrange it that the "diagonalising" series in in the enumeration, just knowing that one term is $n^{-2}$ is not enough to conclude that it converges, and, similarly, knowing that one term in $n$ is not enough to conclude that it diverges.